# ReaderT Design Pattern: Parametrize the Environment

Tags: haskell, dependency-injection

I build a project based on the [ReaderT design pattern](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2017/06/readert-design-pattern). Instead of using a typeclass approach for dependency injection, I choose to use simple injection of handlers as function arguments. This part works fine as one is able to construct a dependency tree statically and define an environment dynamically.

The environment may contain configuration as well as a logging effect `:: String -> IO ()`, an effect of time `:: IO UTCDate` etc. Consider the following minified example

```hs
import Control.Monad.Reader (runReaderT, liftIO, reader, MonadReader, MonadIO)

data SomeEnv 
  = SomeEnv
  { a :: Int
  , logger :: String -> IO ()
  }

class HasLogger a where 
  getLogger :: a -> (String -> IO())

instance HasLogger SomeEnv where 
  getLogger = logger 

myFun :: (MonadIO m, MonadReader e m, HasLogger e) => Int -> m Int
myFun x = do
  logger <- reader getLogger
  liftIO $ logger "I'm going to multiply a number by itself!"
  return $ x * x

doIt :: IO Int
doIt = runReaderT (myFun 1337) (SomeEnv 13 putStrLn)
```

**Is it possible to generalize over the effect of the logger?**

```hs
logger :: String -> m ()
```

With the motivation to use a logger which fits into the monad stack

```hs
myFun x = do
  logger <- reader getLogger
  logger "I'm going to multiply a number by itself!"
  return $ x * x
```

Comment: So you simply want to avoid the need for `liftIO`?

Comment: For example. Also, in Specs one must use some kind of `MonadIO`. In contrast: Functions which do not require any effectfull environment can be tested with monads like `Identity` etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could try the following changes:

- Parameterize the environment record with the "base" monad.
- Make `HasLogger` a two-parameter typeclass that relates the environment to the "base" monad.

Something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneKindSignatures #-}
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Data.Kind (Constraint, Type)

type RT m = ReaderT (SomeEnv m) m

type SomeEnv :: (Type -> Type) -> Type
data SomeEnv m = SomeEnv
  { a :: Int,
    logger :: String -> RT m (),
    -- I'm putting the main fuction in the record,
    -- perhaps we'll want to inject it into other logic, later.
    myFun :: Int -> RT m Int
  }

type HasLogger :: Type -> (Type -> Type) -> Constraint
class HasLogger r m | r -> m where
  getLogger :: r -> String -> m ()

instance HasLogger (SomeEnv m) (RT m) where
  getLogger = logger

_myFun :: (MonadReader e m, HasLogger e m) => Int -> m Int
_myFun x = do
  logger <- reader getLogger
  logger "I'm going to multiply a number by itself!"
  return $ x * x
```

Now `_myFun` doesn't have the `MonadIO` constraint.

We can create a sample environment and run `myFun`:

```
env =
  SomeEnv
    { a = 13,
      logger = liftIO . putStrLn,
      myFun = _myFun
    }

doIt :: IO Int
doIt = runReaderT (myFun env 1337) env
```

One disadvantage of this solution is that the function signatures in the environment become more involved, even with the `RT` type synonym.

---

**Edit**: In order to simplify the signatures in the environment, I tried these alternative definitions:

```
type SomeEnv :: (Type -> Type) -> Type
data SomeEnv m = SomeEnv
  { a :: Int,
    logger :: String -> m (), -- no more annoying ReaderT here.
    myFun :: Int -> m Int
  }

instance HasLogger (SomeEnv m) m where
  getLogger = logger

-- Yeah, scary. This newtype seems necessary to avoid an "infinite type" error.
-- Only needs to be defined once. Could we avoid it completely?
type DepT :: ((Type -> Type) -> Type) -> (Type -> Type) -> Type -> Type
newtype DepT env m r = DepT { runDepT :: ReaderT (env (DepT env m)) m r } 
    deriving (Functor,Applicative,Monad,MonadIO,MonadReader (env (DepT env m)))
instance MonadTrans (DepT env) where
    lift = DepT . lift

env' :: SomeEnv (DepT SomeEnv IO) -- only the signature changes here
env' = 
    SomeEnv
    { a = 13,
      logger = liftIO . putStrLn,
      myFun = _myFun
    }

doIt :: IO Int
doIt = runReaderT (runDepT (myFun env' 1337)) env'
```

`DepT` is basically a `ReaderT`, but one aware that its environment is parameterized by `DeptT` itself. It has the usual instances.

`_myFun` doesn't need to change in this alternative definition.

Comment: This is actually super exciting, there is a lot of cool stuff in your answer I try to wrap my head around. Functional dependencies + type RT seem to break the infinite recursion in the type. I am trying to extend the stack of my application by this approach and will give feedback when I have a result. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Here's a package in Hackage for the `DepT` type: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/dep-t

Comment: thank you @danidiaz, very cool package u've made, I will check it out and follow on GitHub

Comment: just fyi I was also playing around with that approach a bit ending up in with an open environment parametrized by m. https://github.com/keksnicoh/ReaderT-OpenProduct-Environment

Comment: In the README of your package: "It seems that, with DepT, functions in the environment obtain their dependencies anew every time they are invoked. If we change a function in the environment record, all other functions which depend on it will be affected in subsequent invocations. I don't think this happens with "Adventures..." at least when changing an already "assembled" record." - this is the dynamic property of the DepT approach which differs from the static lambda injection approach, thus lambda injection and DepT are kind of orthogonal in the space of runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I want to summarize some results from applying danidiaz approach.

As my project is currently at a GHC version which does not support the second approach, I've followed the first approach. The application consists out of two sub-applications

- a servant application

  `type RT m = ReaderT (Env m) m`
- an internal application

  `type HRT m = CFSM.HouseT (ReaderT (AutomationEnvironment m) m)`

the first approach avoids infinite recursive types at the cost of a relation between the monadic stack and the environment.
As the sub-applications use different monadic stacks, specific environment had to be introduced. It seems that this is avoidable by the second approach due to the introduction of `DepT`.

`MonadIO` constraints could be removed from functions, for example

```hs
mkPostStatusService
  :: (MonadIO m, MonadThrow m, MonadReader e m, HasCurrentTime e, HasRandomUUID e)
  => C.InsertStatusRepository m
  -> PostStatusService m
```

became

```hs
mkPostStatusService
  :: (MonadThrow m, MonadReader e m, HasCurrentTime e m, HasRandomUUID e m)
  => C.InsertStatusRepository m
  -> PostStatusService m
```

Because the environment relates to the application stack, `join` is the substitute for `liftIO`

```hs
currentTime <- reader getCurrentTime >>= liftIO
-- becomes
currentTime <- join (reader getCurrentTime)
```

For unit testing, mock environments are constructed. Due to the removal of `MonadIO`, the mock environment can be constructed without side-effect monads.
An inspection of services which had `MonadIO` and `MonadThrow` were previously performed by defining mock environments like

```hs
data DummyEnvironment = DummyEnvironment (IO T.UTCTime) (IO U.UUID)
instance HasCurrentTime DummyEnvironment where
  getCurrentTime (DummyEnvironment t _) = t
instance HasRandomUUID DummyEnvironment where
  getRandomUUID (DummyEnvironment _ u) = u
```

with the new approach, the side-effects could be remove

```hs
type RT = ReaderT DummyEnvironment (CatchT Identity)
data DummyEnvironment = DummyEnvironment (RT T.UTCTime) (RT U.UUID)
instance HasCurrentTime DummyEnvironment RT where
  getCurrentTime (DummyEnvironment t _) =  t
instance HasRandomUUID DummyEnvironment RT where
  getRandomUUID (DummyEnvironment _ u) =  u
```

As I pointed out, the first approach connects the environment to a specific stack, thus the stack defines the environment.
Next step will be integrating the second approach as it seems to decouple the stack from the environment again using `DepT`.

Comment: Good to know that it worked! From what I've seen, most examples of the "ReaderT pattern" stay close to `IO`, possibly because it's simpler, and you can still mock your dependencies in `IO` in a semi-pure manner using mutable references and the like. As for `DepT`, I think it could be useful to give it a `MonadUnliftIO` instance, so that it works with all the functions of the "unliftio" package http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unliftio

Comment: The complexity aspect should not be underestimated, especially when you work with a team on a code base. My project has the right conditions to do such an experiment and I will observe how the extensions feels over time. When I try the `DepT` approach I will post another answer here to compare the results. Thanks again for showing me these interesting approaches