# Writing a "zooming" function for a ReaderT-like monad transformer

Tags: haskell, monads

I have this `ReaderT`-like monad transformer (inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61782258/1364288) answer):

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneKindSignatures #-}
import Control.Monad.Reader -- from "mtl"
import Data.Kind (Type)

type DepT :: ((Type -> Type) -> Type) -> (Type -> Type) -> Type -> Type
newtype DepT env m r = DepT {toReaderT :: ReaderT (env (DepT env m)) m r}
  deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadReader (env (DepT env m)))

instance MonadTrans (DepT env) where
  lift = DepT . lift
```

And these two parameterized records, to which I give ["rank-2 functor"](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rank2classes-1.4.1/docs/Rank2.html#t:Functor) instances:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import qualified Rank2 -- form rank2classes
import qualified Rank2.TH

type Env :: (Type -> Type) -> Type
data Env m = Env
  { logger :: String -> m (),
    logic :: Int -> m Int
  }
$(Rank2.TH.deriveFunctor ''Env)

type BiggerEnv :: (Type -> Type) -> Type
data BiggerEnv m = BiggerEnv
  { inner :: Env m,
    extra :: Int -> m Int
  }
$(Rank2.TH.deriveFunctor ''BiggerEnv)
```

Intuitively, I expect to be able to write a conversion function with the type:

```
zoom :: forall a. DepT Env IO a -> DepT BiggerEnv IO a
```

This is because `DepT Env IO a` works with "less info" than `DepT BiggerEnv IO a`.

But I'm stuck. Is there a way to write `zoom`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution would be a function like:

```
withDepT ::
  forall small big m a.
  Monad m =>
  ( forall p q.
    (forall x. p x -> q x) ->
    small p ->
    small q
  ) ->
  (forall t. big t -> small t) ->
  DepT small m a ->
  DepT big m a
withDepT mapEnv inner (DepT (ReaderT f)) =
  DepT
    ( ReaderT
        ( \big ->
            let small :: small (DepT small m)
                -- we have a big environment at hand, so let's extract the
                -- small environment, transform every function in the small
                -- environment by supplying the big environment and, as a
                -- finishing touch, lift from the base monad m so that it
                -- matches the monad expected by f.
                small = mapEnv (lift . flip runDepT big) (inner big)
             in f small
        )
    )
```

Where the first argument would be, in the case of `Env`, a function like

```
mapEnv :: (forall x. n x -> m x) -> Env n -> Env m
mapEnv f (Env {logger,logic}) =
    Env { logger = f . logger, logic = f . logic }
```

which changes the monad of the environment. `mapEnv` corresponds to [`Rank2.<$>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rank2classes-1.4.1/docs/Rank2.html#t:Functor) from [rank2classes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rank2classes-1.4.1).

Comment: Well, it seems that the definition of DepT doesn't make GHC's simplifier very happy: https://twitter.com/DiazCarrete/status/1350116413445439493

Comment: What I think (but I'm not 100% sure) would be impossible to write is a `DepT` analogue of `ReaderT`'s `mapReaderT`, which changed the base monad. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.6.2/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html#v:mapReaderT

Answer (score 2):

First, we could create a more general function, `withDepT`, which is similar to the [`withReaderT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Reader.html#v:withReaderT) function.

```
withDepT :: forall env env' m a.
            (env' (DepT env' m) -> env (DepT env m))
            -> DepT env m a
            -> DepT env' m a
withDepT f (DepT m) = DepT (withReaderT f m)
```

And then we can use this to implement `zoom` by providing a function like:

```
biggerEnvToEnv :: BiggerEnv (DepT BiggerEnv IO) -> Env (DepT Env IO)
biggerEnvToEnv (BiggerEnv (Env logger logic) _) = Env logger' logic'
  where
    logger' = mystery . logger
    logic' = mystery . logic

zoom = withDepT biggerEnvToEnv
```

But then we need to implement `mystery`. Let's look at its type:

```
mystery :: forall a. DepT BiggerEnv IO a -> DepT Env IO a
```

Now we can see that `mystery` is the opposite of our desired `zoom` function:

```
zoom :: forall a. DepT Env IO a -> DepT BiggerEnv IO a
```

So we can conclude that it's impossible to naturally derive `zoom` unless `BiggerEnv` and `Env` are isomorphic, which they're not because of the `extra` value in `BiggerEnv`.

Comment: This can be explained by noting that `BiggerEnv`'s `inner` is an `Env m`, and `m` is `DepT BiggerEnv IO`. So `logger` and `logic` might mention `extra`.

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Yeah, it's also important that the `m` in `Env m` is used in a positive position. If `logger` and `logic` were in a negative position like `m () -> String`, then it would be possible to implement `zoom` because we could use `zoom` recursively: `logger' = logger . zoom`

Comment: @4castle A clear explanation, yet my brain still finds the result very unintuitive. If a computation can be run in a restricted environment, why shouldn't it work in a "richer" one? If we take it to an extreme, what about `data TinyEnv m = TinyEnv { }`? That is, an environment which doesn't provide any capabilities. Shouldn't we be able to write a function of type `forall a. DepT TinyEnv IO a -> DepT BiggerEnv IO a`?

Comment: @danidiaz For `TinyEnv`, yes, you can write that function: `zoom = withDepT (const TinyEnv {})`. (`TinyEnv` is a terminal object.)

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson Thinking about `TinyEnv` put me in the correct path for finding the solution. Because it would be mighty strange that you could write `DepT TinyEnv IO a -> DepT BiggerEnv IO a` and also `DepT BiggerEnv IO a -> DepT BiggerEnv IO a`, *but nothing in-between*. The thing we missed is that, when we need `mystery`, we actually have a `BiggerEnv` in scope. It's the parameter to `biggerEnvToEnv `! So we can simply run the `DepT` and then lift the resulting `IO` action into `DepT Env IO`. Problem solved!